# How to link or reference a UI control such as a button in code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've been searching for and trying to figure out how to link a variable to a UI control, so that I can use the variable to perform that particular's UI's actions in code.

For instance, I have a button named NextButton in my MainPage.xaml. I want to define a variable, say `nextButton` of type Button, so that I can perform a button action, say `nextButton.Content` in my c# class. It seems this can only be done in the MainPage.xaml and even with that I can 't figure out how to link the button variable to a particular button.

To make myself even clearer, let me just say that you can do something like this in android by using `findViewById`.

Comment: If you are talking about accessing the UI elements from other class this can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142288/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-static-classes-to-making-the-ui-elements-accessible

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Are you trying to use the variable inside the declaring page or other pages? When you give a control a name, a variable is automatically created for you to use in the page.

Comment: @anderZubi I've looked at it thoroughly but I don't understand the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6142318/1319753

Comment: @Alaa Masoud I gave the control a name in the MainPage.xaml and I want to reference the control in some other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be slightly off what you're after, but if you just want to alter the content of a button, you could use data binding and then provide access point for other classes to the data directly.

To me, it sounds like you want to directly alter another view from another view and that doesn't sound very "MVCey". Have a common underlying data model instead and alter that and have the buttons figure out what they should be doing. If your button performs methods or it's state is handled by methods.

If you really want to provide an access point to the buttons directly, you could just have something like

```
public abstract class CommonUIControls {
    public static Button nextButton = null;
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        CommonUIControls.nextButton = nextButton;
    }
}
```

However, I would not suggest thsi.

Comment: It works, however, I think that it's better design to use data binding to bind your button Content to a variable (this could exist in a static class), then alter the data and let the UI adjust to the data changes instead of accessing the view's controls from another view (keywords: data binding, mvc).

All-in-all, I think the iffy part is that you probably provide "too wide" of an access to your button from other views instead of just providing an access point to the content/data you wish to change.

Hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: I kinda get it. I guess I'll have to read more on exactly how that is done.But for now I'm doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but assuming you have a Button with a specified name on a Window. The only way you can access that button in another class is by having access to that window instance in that class.

I believe the window can be casted as a frameworkelement and you can use the method FindName 
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to find an element inside that window. However this only works is you have access to the instantiated Window inside that class.

Comment: this actually looks like it might work for me. I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

In XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="nextButton" Text="Next" />
```

In the corresponding .cs file the member variable `nextButton` will be part of the class:

```
nextButton.Content = SomethingAmazing;
```